# Please help us translate our family motto: “Having Fun, Spreading Joy”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Please help us translate our family motto. Having Fun, Spreading Joy. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest **lūsitāns / laetificāns**, with two (active singular) present participles.

The first is from the admittedly non-Classical [lūsitō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlusito) 'to play habitually', which is relatively transparent as a frequentative form of [lūdō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ludo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059). 'Having fun' is a slightly tricky concept to translate and I'm not immediately aware of any Latin idioms that are an exact match for it; my choice here is motivated as much by the resemblance to the second participle and the pleasing syllable count as it is by the semantics.

The second is from [laetificō](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=laetifico&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) 'to cheer, make happy'. Post-Classically the present participle used as an adjective can also just mean 'joyous', but the construction is transparent and will be readily understood, I feel, especially with the other participle there.

Translated back very literally this means "habitually playing / making happy". The macra (the lines over the vowels) indicate long vowels but are usually omitted. For pronunciation, the accents are on the *lu* and the *ti*.

Comment: Are present participles able to stand alone; don't they describe what the nouns, they agree with, are doing?

Comment: @tony If it makes you feel better you can imagine these participles as part of a construction like "ego sum lusitans" (i.e. agreeing with "ego") expressed elliptically, but there is absolutely nothing remarkable about using participles non-adjectivally.